# How can we show $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\left\|\lambda R_\lambda(A)x-x\right\|_E=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a (possibly unbounded) linear operator on a Banach space $E$ such that $(0,\infty)\subseteq\rho(A)$ and $$\left\|R_\lambda(A)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\le\frac1\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }\lambda>0.\tag1$$ Can we conclude that $$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\left\|\lambda R_\lambda(A)x-x\right\|_E=0\tag2$$ for all $x\in E$? I'm not able to deduce this from $(1)$; do we need an additional assumption?

(In particular, I'm interested in this result when $A$ is the generator of a strongly continuous contraction semigroup on $E$.)

Comment: Let $A=-Id$, then all your assumptions hold, but $$\lambda R_\lambda(A)-Id = \frac{-\lambda}{1+\lambda} Id -Id=(-2+1/(\lambda+1))Id,$$ so the conclusion does not hold. Did you maybe mean $\lambda R_\lambda(A)x-x$? Respectively, which definition of the resolvent do you use?

Comment: If $R_{\lambda}(A) = (\lambda - A)^{-1}$, then $\lambda R_{\lambda}(-Id) - Id = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1} Id - Id$, so the conclusion definitely holds.

Answer (score 1):

In my class it has been proven in the following way. I assume that $R_\lambda(A) = (\lambda - A)^{-1}$. Let $D(A)$ denote the domain of $A$. If $A$ is the generator of a strongly continuous operator semigroup ($\rm C0$-semigroup in my notation), then $\overline{D(A)} = E$ (it means that $D(A)$ is dense in $E$) and $A$ is a closed operator. So, let $x \in D(A)$, and we'll prove that
$\lambda R_{\lambda}(A) x - x \to 0, \lambda \to + \infty$. Observe that
$$
\lambda R_{\lambda}(A) x - R_{\lambda}(A) x = R_{\lambda}(A)(A - \lambda)x = x
$$
so
$$
\lambda R_{\lambda}(A) x - x = R_{\lambda}(A) x
$$
Hence,
$$
\left\| \lambda R_{\lambda}(A) x - x\right\| = 
\left\|R_{\lambda}(A) x \right\| \leq \left\|R_{\lambda}(A) \right\| \left\| Ax\right\| \leq \frac{1}{\lambda} \left\| Ax\right\| \to 0, \lambda \to + \infty
$$
It's left to notice that $\lambda R_{\lambda}(A)$ is a bounded operator (it's norm is $\leq 1$) and for any $y \in E$, $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \;\exists x \in D(A) : \left\|x - y \right\| \leq \varepsilon$. From proven convergence of $\lambda R_{\lambda}(A)x \to x$ for $x \in D(A)$,
$ \lambda_n R_{\lambda_n}(A)x \to x$ as
$n\to\infty$ for
any sequence $\lambda_n \to +\infty, n\to\infty$. Let's prove that
for any $y \in E$, $\lambda_n R_{\lambda_n}(A)y$
is a Cauchy sequence, denoting $\lambda_n R_{\lambda_n}(A) = B_n$ for simplicity. Let $\varepsilon > 0$, $x \in D(A), \left\| x - y\right\| \leq \varepsilon$. As $B_n x$ is convergent and hence Cauchy, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n, m \geq N :
\left\|B_n x - B_m x \right\| \leq \varepsilon$.
$$
\left\|B_n y - B_m y\right\| \leq 
\left\|B_n y -  B_n x\right\| + 
\left\|B_m y -  B_m x\right\| +
\left\|B_n x -  B_m x\right\| \leq \\
\leq
\left\|B_n \right\| \left\| x - y \right\| + \left\|B_m \right\| \left\| x - y \right\| + \varepsilon \leq
\left\| x - y \right\| + \left\| x - y \right\| +  \varepsilon \leq 3 \varepsilon
$$
So $B_n y$ is Cauchy and hence convergent, since $E$ is a Banach space. By uniqueness of limit,
$B_n y = \lambda_n R_{\lambda_n}(A) y \to y, n\to\infty$,
and by arbitrariness of $\lambda_n$,
$\lambda R_{\lambda}(A) y \to y$, $\lambda \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

So let me share you what i found from "Konrad Schmüdgen Unbounded self-adjoint operators on hilbert spaces".[image]
probably we should have $$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\lambda R_\lambda(A)x=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda s}B(s)x\ ds = $$ as far as i know as $\lambda$ goes to $\infty$. Integral at the right behaves like a dirac measure at $s=0$. Therefore we get $B(0)x=x$ where $B$ is contraction semigroup generated by $A$. This answer was very hand-wavy but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$,
$$
    \lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x-x=(\lambda I-A)^{-1}Ax.
$$
Therefore
$$
       \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x=x,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A).
$$
For a general $x$, let $y\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ be chosen so that $\|x-y\| < \epsilon/2$. Then,
\begin{align}
    \|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x-x\|&=\|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}(x-y)-(x-y)\| \\
       &+\|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}y-y\| \\
       &\le 2\|x-y\|+\|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}y-y\|
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
   \limsup_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x-x\| \le 2\|x-y\| < \epsilon.
$$
This is true for every $\epsilon > 0$, which gives
$$
       \limsup_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x-x\|=0.
$$
Therefore,
$$
          \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda (\lambda I-A)^{-1}x=x,\;\;\; x\in X.
$$

Comment: This requires $\mathcal{D}(A)$ to be dense (which is true for generators of $C_0$-semigroups, in which the OP is particularly interested, but not in general).

Comment: @JochenGlueck : And if $\lambda R(\lambda)x\rightarrow x$ as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$ holds for all $x$, then the domain of $A$ is dense.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The reason I mentioned it was just that the density assumption did not occur in the original post, so the result is not true under the general assumptions made there.